# Show that countable sum of meager sets is meager set

Tags: general-topology

I have to prove that countable sum of meager sets is also meager set.

Let's say that $A = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ and $A_{n} = \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}F_{n,j}$, where $F_{n,j}$ is a nowhere dense set.

So we have to show, that $A = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}F_{n,j}$ is meager, but I don't know how.

Is it just a consequence of the fact that Cartesian product of two countable sets is also countable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's all it is. The point is that $\mathcal{F}=\{F_{n, j}: n,j\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable collection of nowhere dense sets (countable since "countable times countable is countable"), and $A=\bigcup\mathcal{F}$.

To help visualize this, fix a concrete bijection $f$ from $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\mathbb{N}$ (e.g.  [the Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function)), and let $\pi_0, \pi_1$ be its "projections" (that is, $f(x, y)=z$ iff $\pi_0(z)=x$ and $\pi_1(z)=y$). Now we can write $A$ as $$A=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}F_{\pi_0(i), \pi_1(i)}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know how to write that formally :)